# WSO2 EMM device registration: I receive e-mail without login and password for register my device

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-iot

I install and deploy WSO2EMM on server with public ip, then I configured it. I replace all "localhost" to ip in .xml and .json files. I send email for enroll my device, but this email contains only link to download agent and no login/password to registration it. I find two templates for emails at /repository/conf/notification-messages.xml:

```
    <Notifications>
    <NotificationMessage type="enrol">
        <Subject>Enroll your Device with WSO2 MDM</Subject>
        <Header>Dear {first-name},</Header>
        <Body>
            You have been registered to the WSO2 MDM. Below is the link to enroll.
        </Body>
        <Url>{downloadUrl}</Url>
        <Footer1>
            Best Regards,
        </Footer1>
        <Footer2>
            WSO2 MDM Team.
        </Footer2>
        <Footer3>
            http://www.wso2.com
        </Footer3>
    </NotificationMessage>
    <NotificationMessage type="userRegistration">
        <Subject>Enroll your Device with WSO2 MDM</Subject>
        <Header>Dear {first-name},</Header>
        <Body>
You have been registered to WSO2 MDM with following credentials.
Domain: {domain-name}
Username: {user-name}
Password: {password}
Below is the link to enroll.
        </Body>
        <Url>{downloadUrl}</Url>
        <Footer1>
            Best Regards,
        </Footer1>
        <Footer2>
            WSO2 MDM Team.
        </Footer2>
        <Footer3>
            http://www.wso2.com
        </Footer3>
    </NotificationMessage>
</Notifications>
```

I receive template "enrol". I try insert placeholders {user-name} and {password} into it but unfortunately: variables miss in the scope of mail, they displayed as plain text. I search any file where I can switch type of email template but I didn't find it. How I can take credentials for registration device?

Answer (score 0):

What is the EMM version you are using? In EMM 2.0 it is only matter of changing the configurations in axis2.xml file. Doc can be found [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM200/General+Server+Configurations).

Comment: Firstly, thank you for quick answer. Yes, I am using EMM 2.0.0. So, I did recommended steps and I am still having enroll-email 
"Dear TestUser,

You have been registered to the WSO2 MDM. Below is the link to enroll.
https://my.host:9443/emm-web-agent/enrollment

Best Regards,
WSO2 MDM Team.
http://www.wso2.com" but I am expecting see something like 
"Dear TestUser,

You have been registered to the WSO2 MDM. 
Below is the link to enroll.
https://my.host:9443/emm-web-agent/enrollment

Best Regards,
WSO2 MDM Team.
http://www.wso2.com"

Comment: Sorry, I mean:
 I am expecting see something like 
"Dear TestUser,

You have been registered to the WSO2 MDM. 
Your login: somelogin
your password: 12345
Below is the link to enroll.
https://my.host:9443/emm-web-agent/enrollment
Best Regards,
WSO2 MDM Team."
What do I should configure to have such email?

Comment: Did you try to create a new user using EMM console?

Comment: Yes, I did. I create new user and try enroll him by EMM console.

Comment: Which platform you running this? Is it Windows?

Comment: No, I run this on Linux. And I resolve this issue: cause is a caching inside WSO2. So, when I create some new users it work correctly for them. Problem was connected with first created user only.
Thanks for help:-)